# Netsuite Account Statement PDF/HTML Template

Tags: pdf, scripting, freemarker, netsuite

I need to display the following information on PDF account statements in Netsuite;

- Customer Name
- Accounts Contact (or Primary Contact)
- Default Email Address
- Phone / Fax Number

From the look of it, I can't edit the actual entry/transaction forms, so I need a way to show these values using the scriptIDs; `${record.customer}`* or `${statement.contactprimary}`* etc. and including those on the template..

*I know these are incorrect IDs, just using them for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement template has access to the `customer` record, so you can print most of these fields:

```
<p>
    Customer Name: ${customer.companyname} <br/>
    Email: ${customer.email} <br/>
    Phone: ${customer.phone} <br/>
    Fax: ${customer.fax} <br/>
    Primary Contact: ${customer.contact} <br/>
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! @michoel 
the script for primary contact doesn't seem to work though?
Also, am I able to use scripting to show only some fields from the default billing address?
I only want to show `ATTENTION`, `ADDRESS 1` and `ADDRESS 2`

Comment: @SimonG It works when I test. Are you sure that the customer has a Primary Contact defined? If you wanted to access specific contact fields, or other contacts besides for the primary, you would need to create a custom field to source it in. The additional fields you are after are `${customer.billattention}`, `${customer.billaddr1}` and `${customer.billaddr2}`.

Comment: yes that was the problem, no primary contact specified for the customer I was looking at! Those other scripts are spot-on, thank you! 
I have one last query with the account statement; In the item list there is a column for the invoice amount, and a column for '**payments**' (credits/deposits) But I want invoices that have only been partially paid to be visible; is it possible with scriptIDs to show the '**amount applied**' (on each invoice) within the item list on statements?